# How $exceptionHandler works

Tags: angularjs

I did find a way to handle uncaught exceptions in `angularjs` by using predefined `$exceptionHandler` service. According to the doc, I'm delegating exceptions manually by using `try {...}` - `catch(e)`. See below

```
try {
   $scope.loadImage();
}catch (e){
   console.log(e);
}
```

It is working absolutely fine
 But I eager to know **how could I handle uncaught exceptions in angular way** ? Can anyone please share a working example ?

Comment: "I did find a way to handle uncaught exceptions" ... "how could I handle uncaught exceptions" - ???

Comment: Will you please elaborate sir ?

Comment: You wrote that you have found a solution, but then ask for solution. That's a contradiction.

Comment: Oh, my point was by doing it in `try{}` `catch()`. I was curious about the Is there any angular way of doing that ?

Answer (score 0):

It is explained [in the API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler).

> ```
> angular.module('exceptionOverride', []).factory('$exceptionHandler', function() {
>   return function(exception, cause) {
>     exception.message += ' (caused by "' + cause + '")';
>     throw exception;
>   };
> });
> ```
>
> This example will **override the normal action of
>   `$exceptionHandler`**, to make angular exceptions fail hard when they
>   happen, instead of just logging to the console.
>
> Note, that code executed in event-listeners (even those registered
>   using jqLite's on/bind methods) does not delegate exceptions to the
>   `$exceptionHandler` (unless executed during a digest). If you wish,
>   you can manually delegate exceptions, e.g. `try { ... } catch(e) {
>   $exceptionHandler(e); }`

Comment: How would that handle uncaught exceptions?